# Submit formData with Reactjs doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, forms, multipartform-data

I'm trying to use formData() to submit a login form using Reactjs and Hooks, but it doesn't work.
Values returned from the formData components seem to be correct. I have try it both with Axios and Fetch and none of them work.
I have also tried different ways of populating the formData element, even with fixed strings, but none of them work.

I'm sure I'm making some naive mistake but, I can't find it.
Could some of you help me please?

Thank you

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function useLoginForm() {
    const [field, setField] = useState({email: '', password: ''})

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setField({...field, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }
    const onBlurHandler = (event) => {
        setField({...field,[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
    const fileHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
    }
    const submitHandler = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        for(let [name, value] of loginFormData) {
            console.log(`KEY: ${name} VALUE = ${value}`);// Logging outcome details
          }

        const url = 'https://my_url/post'
        }

        console.log(`Submit --> ${field.email} - Password ${field.password}`);

        try{
            const response = await axios.post(url, loginFormData,{
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" /* ; boundary=${loginFormData._boundary}*/
                },
            }
            )
            console.log(response.data)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
      
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{field.email} - {field.password}</p>
            <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onChange={changeHandler} /* onBlur={onBlurHandler} */></input>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={changeHandler} /* onBlur={onBlurHandler} */></input>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default useLoginForm
```

```
Results:

KEY: email VALUE = xyz_xyz@VBM.com      useLoginForm.js:47
KEY: password VALUE = Xxxxxx            useLoginForm.js:47
Submit --> xyz_xyz@VBM.com - Password Xxxxxx    useLoginForm.js:57

XHRPOSThttps://my_url/post
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 6681ms]

    1
    -----------------------------345147470230284216993885766804
    2
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
    3
    4

    xyz_xyz@VBM.com

    5
    -----------------------------345147470230284216993885766804
    6
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
    7
    8

    Xxxxxx

    9
    -----------------------------345147470230284216993885766804--
    10
```

Comment: your server side is not receiving the values, is that it?

Comment: No, that's not the answer. I'm receiving a "404 Not Found". So, the user (email) is not correct